# Cancel asking to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

This is probably very obvious, but if you vote to close a question which is subsequently edited to improve it (say to clarify how it's different from another one), how do you cancel your vote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag for [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/168244) was... rescinded. It was updated to [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) on [June 10, 2013](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/915/9) and subsequently implemented on [July 21, 2013](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/915/11), turning it into [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Users are now able to "undo" their close-votes in a similar way that one can retract/modify your regular vote to a post. A visual display of close-vote retraction resembles:

[image: Undo close-vote]

The display clearly states that "you have already voted to close this question", with the option to "retract [the] close vote". Once retracted, voting-to-close on that specific is closed to you with a display that summarizes your voting history:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In the light of Stefan's answer, we should have the convention that if you would rescind your vote-to-close then you should leave a comment to the effect saying "I voted to close on an earlier version of this question, I now consider it worth keeping.".  We could have the convention that someone else who *still* thought it worth closing then left a comment saying "I'm taking over *X*'s vote to close.".

On MO, on any question where there's some disagreement, or something a little out of the ordinary, we start a discussion on meta so that people can make their case.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable community-driven work-around

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Yes, I think that we shouldn't expect the software to do _everything_!

Answer (score 8):

This has been discussed at meta.stackoverflow.com: [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

It's been tagged *status-declined*.

Comment: Oh: that seems rather unhelpful. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @joseph note that close votes automatically expire after 2 days anyway. Most votes that attempt to reach a threshold, expire, so that they don't build up over an absurd (say, 10 year) period of time

Comment: After almost 2 years, this has been reversed...