# Do close votes expire?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

According to the link within [Cancel asking to close?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/cancel-asking-to-close) we can *not* rescind our close votes.

There was a popular question recently (I won't link to it because I don't want to be seen as rep hunting) that received 4 close votes. It teetered on the precipice for a few days, and managed to stay open. When viewing the question now (about a month later) the close votes are no longer present.

So, my question is: do close votes expire?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, after four days, provided the question has received enough views.

See [Close Votes expire too soon for low-traffic tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581)

Comment: awesome, thanks Charles :)